# Is it possible to add style plugins?

Tags: 8, panels

I would like to allow users to choose a style for each pane and choose options such as margin and font size. It is clear how to do this in Drupal 7. But I can't seem to figure out whether it's possible in Drupal 8.

Note:
It could be an issue where the stylizer module isn't running properly. I see that the styles plugin is in the directory under the panels module. But even though panels are enabled I don't see any style options on the panes when I attempt to configure them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the functionality does not yet exist for Drupal 8

https://www.drupal.org/node/2296437